# Fetch distinct values of multiple fields in one SOLR query

Tags: java, solr

Is there any way to query distinct values of multiple fields in single SOLR query?

I know of facet field, but it works for one field at a time.

facet:true, facet.field:XYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide multiple `facet.field` keys in your query:

```
facet.field=field1&facet.field=field2&facet.field=field3
```

> The `facet.field` parameter identifies a field that should be treated as a facet. It iterates over each Term in the field and generate a facet count using that Term as the constraint. *This parameter can be specified multiple times in a query to select multiple facet fields*.

You can also provide separate settings for each field through the `f.<field>.<setting>` syntax:

```
f.field1.facet.prefix=foo
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that we can provide multiple facet fields as well. Will give this a try.